# sharepoint moss 2007: How do I show different categories of events to different categories of users?

Tags: events, sharepoint-2007

Consider a user group: Canadians, I want to show them only events with either Canadian category or Canadian location. Is this possible?

Comment: Be more specific.  How are these events displayed?  List?  Webpart?  etc...

Comment: I'm adding events to the collaboration portal template calender. I've put an events webpart on my homepage and I currently show them in an all events view. I've been looking through the configurations for the available views, but nothing seems to be right.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at audience targeting http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sharepoint+target+audiences